# Where can discord bots find the ffmpeg buildpack heroku

Tags: python, heroku, ffmpeg, discord.py

I'm making a bot which outputs a mp3 file to the voice chat with discord.py, It works localy by using:

`vc.play(discord.FFmpegPCMAudio(executable="ffmpeg/bin/ffmpeg.exe", source=noise.mp3))`

However I'm now hosting it on Heroku, i have the buildpack installed but how can my code access it in replacement of the code above

Comment: You don't need to specify the `executable` parameter if `ffmpeg` is part of `$PATH` which should be the case if you are using the ffmpeg Heroku buildpack.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You didn't include your code, so I didn't know if you want it to **play when you write command in discord or when the bot is ready**, so I decided to make bot play when it's ready (if you want it to join on the command you can modify my code). Also, I think it will be easier if you use **youtube_dl** for this.

```
import discord
from discord.ext import commands
import youtube_dl

Token = "XXXXXX" #your token         
client = commands.Bot(command_prefix = ":") 


ydl_opts = {
    'format': 'bestaudio/best',
    'postprocessors': [{
        'key': 'FFmpegExtractAudio',
        'preferredcodec': 'mp3',
        'preferredquality': '192',
    }],
}   

def endSong(guild, path):
    os.remove(path)

url = "https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dQw4w9WgXcQ" #link to your song on YouTube
with youtube_dl.YoutubeDL(ydl_opts) as ydl:
    file = ydl.extract_info(url, download=True)
    guild = "1234567890" #id of your server which you can get by right clicking on server name and clicking "Copy ID" (developer mode must be on)
    path = str(file['title']) + "-" + str(file['id'] + ".mp3")

channel = client.get_channel(1234567890) #id of your channel (you get it like server id, but by right clicking on channel)                         
voice_client = await channel.connect()                                           

voice_client.play(discord.FFmpegPCMAudio(path), after=lambda x: endSong(guild, path))
voice_client.source = discord.PCMVolumeTransformer(voice_client.source, 1)
    
while voice_client.is_playing(): #waits until song ends
    await asyncio.sleep(1)
else:
    await voice_client.disconnect() #and disconnects
    print("Disconnected")
```

Also remember to include 4 buildpacks on Heroku to make sure everything will work (`Your APP > Settings > Buildpacks`):

- heroku/python
- https://github.com/heroku/heroku-buildpack-apt.git
- https://github.com/jonathanong/heroku-buildpack-ffmpeg-latest.git
- https://github.com/xrisk/heroku-opus.git

And check if you have all of these in your **requirements.txt**:

- pip
- youtube_dl
- discord.py[voice]
- ffmpeg
- PyNaCl

Comment: Your post helped a lot thanks, but you sould know... I can identify the rickroll youtube link on sight so you didnt get me XD XD